# How do I escape the sinking ship in Chapter 15?

Tags: uncharted-3

In Uncharted 3 chapter 15, when the ship overturns and starts sinking, I can't seem to find a way out.

I have failed to go to the next step where the kidnapper shoots the glass window for the ship to finally sink as in the video i saw.  I tried restarting the whole chapter, but it still brings me to the same point where every move is suicide.

How can I escape the sinking ship?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a sealed metal vent that Drake can open.  Swim directly forward you will see it slightly to your right. It will prompt you to mash triangle to break it open.

Comment: I passed that stage and reached where drake kicks a door open, climbs on the upper side and runs through the path to the end of the ship. At the end of the ship there is no option to fall inside a space where drake finds his abducter before the ship sinks finally.

Comment: Ahh ok I believe you will see a red rope on the right of the wall above the final gap. Jump on it and climb up

Comment: Am referring to this; https://youtu.be/m0xJH_zjdPk   at 05:22. When i reach there, the end of the ship is just an empty space, its not like in this video.